# How to prevent tags from overlapping against one another

Tags: html, css

I am creating tag links in my application, and I am struggling to get the individual tags to align nicely with each other (i.e. without overlapping etc.)

Here is my markup

```css
a.user-interest {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #696969;
    border: 3px solid #A9A9A9;
    padding: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>  
     <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <h4>Interests</h4>
    <p class="interest">    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Science Fiction</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Community Service</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Craftsmanship</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Exercising and Healthcare</a>    
    </p>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the tags to align nicely?

Comment: Could you link a code pen/show an picture of your problem?

Comment: I created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you, if anything is wrong you can update it

Comment: Nothing is overlapping in the snippet result in question...

Comment: @Reyno Yeah, thanks. That's really cool. I'll have to look into how to do that (I mostly post questions on Python and C/C++, so I'm a newbie with HTML5 stuff!). Thanks for the link.

Comment: No one browses this site on mobile to answer questions. If something happens only on specific devices, it's better to say so in the initial question. Just as an info for future questions. Glad you got this one figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your CSS, I also recommend using `margin` to fully see the separation (It's up to you).

```css
a.user-interest {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #696969;
    border: 3px solid #A9A9A9;
    padding: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>  
     <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <h4>Interests</h4>
    <p class="interest">    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Science Fiction</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Community Service</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Craftsmanship</a>    
      <a class="user-interest" href="#">Exercising and Healthcare</a>    
    </p>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to change nothing in the end result, which already looked fine in the question.

Comment: @Esko I don't know why you (and others) are not able to replicate the issue. This solution solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli What browser are you using?

Comment: Side note: margin top and bottom don't work on inline elements (which an `a` is by default), hence the reason for `display: inline-block`

Comment: @Esko: Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit). Running on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS.  But I had the same problem with FF

Comment: @Esko overlapping happens on mobile